# How can I unpin multiple files in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is this possible to do in VS Code? The problem I have is that I've accumulated hundreds of files that are pinned and show up whenever I open a folder and the only way to remove them seems to be to do so one-by-one.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to unpin multiple editors at a time. But there are some ways to help with closing many one by one:

- In the Explorer View, use the "Open Editors" sub view (if you don't see it, you need to unhide it by going into the three-dot menu at the top right of the sidebar). Then just spam click the pin icon of the top-most item, which will unpin it, and make another pinned item take its place in the subview listing.
- Middle click the left-most pinned editor's tab handle, which will close it (which as a side-effect, unpins it).

Information about whether an editor is pinned is stored in the workspace's `.../User/workspaceSettings/<workspace hash>/state.vscdb` file. While it may be theoretically possible to fiddle with it to achieve this, I don't know exactly how.

If you think such a feature would be useful, you can [create a feature-request issue ticket on the VS Code GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Comment: I found this while looking for a way to create a workspace with pre-pinned files. I haven't found that yet, but had a thought on this Q: it seems like you could delete the `.../User/workspaceStorage/<workspace hash>/` folder (or at least the vscdb file) to clear all of those pinned files. I'm not sure if Code would recover or just force you to create a new workspace.

Comment: @SamErde the workspace folder (the codebase / repo clone / whatever) doesn't get deleted when you delete that. That's just a folder of VS Code data _for_ the workspace folder. so the answer to your question is "it depends what you mean when you say 'workspace'".

Comment: I get that--the idea is simply to clear the location that sets pinned files specifically. :)